# reLayout not always working as per example

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to get a similar layout to:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html

Instead I'm getting this:
http://isotope-jul-2012.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

Clicking on the THIRD element of each row creates gaps along the top & bottom and this doesn't happen on the demo page. I can't figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your original .profile dimensions in - but changing the margin on it as well as the column width, all elements behave [as they should](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7gf/).